# "Bitmap size exceeds VM budget"

Tags: android, bitmap, virtual-machine

Once in a while i get the error message "Bitmap size exceeds VM budget". It happens when i open 20 activities one after another where each of the activities holds a 500x300 PNG picture. I didn't have the problem when i implemented the pictures in my XML layouts with android:background="@drawable/xxxxxxxx".

The error first occured when i implemented the pictures in my Java code.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ImVpic"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

ImageView pic;
pic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImVpic);
pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture);
```

How can i get rid of that error? What is missing in my code? I mean it actually works, but from time to time it throws that error which is really annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very common question you see on SO. It seems while loading the image, available memory is low. Make sure you are not keeping for long references for images, which allows dalvik to reclaim the memory from unused images (or) objects.

Comment: The reference for my images is very short actually (4 letters). Are you sure that's the problem? I mean the app still crashes even though the references are short.

Comment: It is not about reference size. If your reference points to "Object" that object will not eligible for GC.

Comment: @JohnD 'Reference' does not mean 'filename'. It means that some variable in your program is still pointing to the old texture, so it can't be claimed by garbage collector.

Comment: Is it maybe because i use the same name for the reference in each activity? I always use the same code that you can see above. I only change the R.drawable.xxxxxxxxxx for each activity. Should i give different names for the reference in each activity? I mean like this: Activity1: pic ; Activity2 pic2 ; Activity3 pic3 ; ....